# Powershell command to convert CSV file to xlsx

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, command

i  have many files like 20-30 in csv format in a directory. I want to convert them to xlsx format using powershell. Please provide me the script as i am the beginner  in this.

somw where in online i found powershell script which only convert one file at a time. pls help in converting all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take that powershell script you found online and run it each time for each csv file you have found

Lets say they are all in a directory called C:\temp
Then you should be able to do something like

```
foreach($item in Get-Childitem C:\temp){onlinefunction.ps1 $item}
```

So `Get-ChildItem` will go through a given directory and return an object with all the files in it. You will need to parse and modify this to suit your needs

`foreach($item...` part will loop through the object returned by `get-childitem` and go through it one by one. For each $item it will run `onlinefunction.ps1 $item`

Hopefully that script you found is robust enough to accept single inputs, otherwise you will need to play around with it

Comment: Hey.. thanks for the reply.. it seems the  script is not working. Can you please provide me tthe new script for my requirement ?? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Sorry mate,I don't think this is that kind of website, but if you post your script I can try point out whats wrong.

If you copy paste the following code (its simple), but it might help you out with how the inputs work  "param($theinput); write-output $theinput" . Save that to a ps1 file, then you should be able to call it with a single input parameter and have it print out whatever you input. You just need to apply the same principle to that script you already have.

Comment: can u help me the below script to work for a directory          $xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$xl.visible = $true
$Workbook = $xl.workbooks.open("$loglocation\errors_$server.csv")
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets

$Workbook.SaveAs("$loglocation\errors_$server.xls",1)
$Workbook.Saved = $True

$xl.Quit()

Comment: please alter the script given by cristain to do for bulk csv files. as i am new to this i found difficult in alter this script. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the code below:

```
$xl = new-object -comobject excel.application
$xl.visible = $true
$Workbook = $xl.workbooks.open("$loglocation\errors_$server.csv")
$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets

$Workbook.SaveAs("$loglocation\errors_$server.xls",1)
$Workbook.Saved = $True

$xl.Quit()
```

Or use this tutorial:

https://code.adonline.id.au/csv-to-xlsx-powershell/

regards.

Comment: thanks cristain.. this is what i found on online but it converts only one file at a time.. but i need to do it for bulk csv files in a directory.. as i am new to this i found difficult in alter this script.